# How can I create some Dictionary in a root class that will be shared by all derived classes?

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class and five other classes that inherit from it.
I want to hold one instance of Dictionary in this abstract class - and give all the other classes the ability to add/remove values from this Dictionary.

I prefer to not define this Dictionary as 'Static'.

How can I do it?

Comment: To be clear, you want this dictionary to be shared across all instances of classes that inherit from your abstract class, or you just want a dictionary that is visible to subclasses?

Comment: What is wrong with `static`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way of doing this might be to have a separate Singleton class that holds your dictionary, and make that singleton class a property of your base class. This will let you avoid use of static, while ensuring one instance of the singleton class encapsulating the dictionary. Making it a protected member of your abstract class allows access to all subclasses to the single instance of your class containing the dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

Define it as

> protected Dictionary d ...

It will be visible to all subclasses.

The static keyword is the wrong choice since it defines a dictionary shared to all instances of the class. It's a completely different thing

Comment: but this will be not have shared memory - one instance for all the inherit

Comment: So you want static (shared in VB) behaviour but don't want to declare it static? Why?

Comment: if you want it static define it as static.... or as protected static and create a protected property that references it (if this makes sense!!!)

Comment: because when i have more then one instance of the object - i will use the same shared memory even if i define the second object using 'new' => so the two different object will have one Dictionary